Close side pane in model-driven application on form exit
In model-driven application, I want to close side panes when a user leaves a form.
Where to put the script for side panes closing? Or how to call it when leaving the form? I was not able to find any handler for "OnExit" / "OnClose" / "OnUnload" on the form. Not even any handler on the grid / view to call the script to close side panes.
I already tried adding the script to "OnSave" handle in the form, which works only in case the user press "Save & Close" button. However, my users usually do not need to click that button and directly somewhere else.
The story:

User goes to a model-driven application and opens a grid with records for a table "ideas".

The user opens a record from the grid and the form loads.

When a for loads, side pane opens. In the side pane is custom page to show relevant information for that opened record using parameter in custom page.

When a user clicks the "Back" button or even selects another table from the left menu, the side pane still stays open. With the details for a record which is already closed.


I have this script to close all side panes:
function closeAllPanes() {
    var allPanes = Xrm.App.sidePanes.getAllPanes();
    allPanes.forEach(function(pane) {
        pane.close().catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error closing pane: ", error);
        });
    });
    console.log("Side panes closed.")
}

